# Visual Studio Performance Profiler - Source Information is Not Available - .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, profiler

In the VS2022 performance profiler, many of the views have a pane at the bottom where it will show the source code annotated line-by-line with percentages and number of samples. Even with a new .NET 3.5 solution (to verify it's not in our codebase), the source information pane shows *No Source Information Is Available*. Whereas with .NET 4+, it works perfectly.

Is this available only on .NET 4+, is there something I need to do for .NET 2/3, a bug in VS/Windows, or is it something peculiar to my system?

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio 2022 as administrator fixed my profiling session's source viewer.

- Open the Start Menu
- Find Visual Studio 2022 (or whatever version)
- Right-click the start menu entry and select "Run as administrator"

I'm using VS 2022 17.4.3 & .NET 7.0.101.